# Particle の attached to relative time expression いつか

Tags: english-to-japanese

I think I know what it means nontheless the construction is pretty strange for my Indoeuropean mind.

I heard it in a song and the line goes like this:
いつかの風頬に触れて春を伝えるでしょう

I think it says that someday the wind will touch her cheeks (as the winds blows) and will tell her about spring. However, it sounds strange to me to say something like "someday's wind" and I would like to know why の is attached to いつか. I have never found a lesson explaing this construction so an explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this いつか is referring not to sometime in the future, but to a certain unspecified time in the past. This is a fairly common sense of the word particularly in poetic contexts, listed as the second meaning in the [デジタル大辞泉 entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/13031/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8B/):

> **２** 過去の不定の時を表す。いつぞや。以前。「何時か来た道」「何時か読んだ本」

In this case, the song's lyrics seem to be about returning to a place and reminiscing about memories the singer shared with someone there. So I think いつかの風 is referring to "the wind from back then", indicating that the singer is equating the wind they are feeling right now with the wind that they felt in their memories.

There are a number of similar cases where the past is poetically blended with the present in this song - the final line about 今 時を越えて 二人の影 そっと重なるでしょう is the most explicit, but there's also a line about あの日見た月を探して "searching for the moon I saw that day". あの日見た月 and いつかの風 are quite similar constructions (they could easily be rephrased as あの日の月, いつか感じた風 etc.) Does that help to clarify why the の is used here?